# Load from a 64-bit address into other register than rax

Tags: assembly, x86-64

On x64, loading from a 64-bit absolute address (that is, dereferencing a 64-bit immediate) can be done by

```
movabs addr64, %rax
```

However, when the destination register is any other than `rax` the assembler gives an error message saying `operand size mismatch for movabs`. What am I missing?

Comment: Nit: your assembler instruction above is neither Intel nor AT&T syntax; in Intel syntax,  it's `MOV RAX, [addr64]` while in AT&T it's `movabs addr64, %rax`.

Comment: Related on RE: http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2627/what-is-the-meaning-of-movabs-in-gas-x86-att-syntax

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [MOV instruction document](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOV.html) you can see that you can move a 64-bit *immediate* to any registers, but loads/stores involving a 64-bit immediate absolute ***address*** can only work with Areg

| Opcode | Instruction | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A0 | MOV AL,*moffs8** | Move byte at (*seg:offset*) to AL. |
| REX.W + A0 | MOV AL,*moffs8** | Move byte at (*offset*) to AL. |
| A1 | MOV AX,*moffs16** | Move word at (*seg:offset*) to AX. |
| A1 | MOV EAX,*moffs32** | Move doubleword at (*seg:offset*) to EAX. |
| REX.W + A1 | MOV RAX,*moffs64** | Move quadword at (*offset*) to RAX. |
| A2 | MOV *moffs8*,AL | Move AL to (*seg:offset*). |
| REX.W + A2 | MOV *moffs8****,AL | Move AL to (*offset*). |
| A3 | MOV *moffs16**,AX | Move AX to (*seg:offset*). |
| A3 | MOV *moffs32**,EAX | Move EAX to (*seg:offset*). |
| REX.W + A3 | MOV *moffs64**,RAX | Move RAX to (*offset*). |

As you can see there's no ModR/M byte to encode the register number. Since this is less commonly used than moving a 64-bit immediate to a register it won't be a problem. If really needed it can be done in 2 instructions

> `MOVABS` is the GAS opcode name for the `MOV` opcode forms `MOV Areg, [Offs64]` and `MOV [Offs64], Areg`. In Yasm's NASM syntax mode, you can get this form by saying `MOV AX, [qword xxx]`. Yasm's GAS syntax mode accepts `MOVABS` (for GAS compatibility). **Note this form is only valid with Areg (AL/AX/EAX/RAX) as the source/destination register.**
>
> http://cvs.tortall.net/pipermail/yasm-devel/2006-March/000579.html

Comment: I don't reproduce this on Ubuntu 14.04 Intel Core i5-3210M  binutils 2.25 with [this code](https://github.com/cirosantilli/assembly-cheat/blob/73dd35d9e4978ab0c461464df58ba0699fce9979/x86-64/gas/movabs.s). And the Intel manual says `MOV r64, imm64` should work. Maybe something changed since?

Comment: @CiroSantilli六四事件法轮功 I think `mov r64, imm64` is valid for all registers but `mov Areg, addr64` is only valid for A registers. "`movabs %al,0xe400000000004049` is supposed to store the value of al in the address 0xe400000000004049" so it's not moving the immediate value to/from the register http://www.cplusplusdevelop.com/508_9928837/

Comment: `movabs $0x1000000000000000, %rax` is similar to `mov rax, 0x1000000000000000` but `movabs 0x1000000000000000, %rax` is similar to `mov rax, [qword 0x1000000000000000]`

Comment: Ah, OK, _dereferencing_ an immediate.

Answer (score 3):

For any register other than `%rax` one can replace it by two instructions:

```
48 bb f0 de bc 9a 78 56 34 12   mov    $0x123456789abcdef0,%rbx
48 8b 1b                        mov    (%rbx),%rbx
```

This is longer than the single one,

```
48 a1 f0 de bc 9a 78 56 34 12   mov    0x123456789abcdef0,%rax
```

hence you'd quite probably prefer `movabs` (the latter) if you can use it.

Comment: Note that both forms with an 8-byte thing and no ModRM (imm64 and 64-bit absolute moffs) are called `movabs` in AT&T syntax.  (And GAS / objdump uses it in Intel-syntax mode as well). Including `movabs 0x123456789abcdef0, %al`, which is a separate opcode (`a0`) from the `a1` opcode that gives us moffs16/32/64 (AX/EAX/RAX) depending on operand-size.

Comment: So, fun fact, `movabs 0x123456789abcdef0, %si` or `%dil` don't have an exact drop-in "replacement" / implementation.  You need a full 64-bit register to hold the address (if RIP-relative or 32-bit absolute won't reach), but `mov` to an 8 or 16-bit register only modifies that 8 or 16 bits of register state, merging into the full reg.  It's possible to imagine cases where that was actually desirable, and you didn't want to `mov $imm64, %reg` / `movzbl` or `movsbl` extending load into the full register.

Comment: @PeterCordes: I'd recommend xchg/mov64/xchg. (Where the first xchg could be a mov but xchg with rax has a short encoding).

Comment: @Joshua: Interesting, yes that would do the trick without needing to spill any architectural state from registers to anywhere else.  When AL/AX is special, look to 8086 techniques. :P  (But no, mov doesn't make sense.  If the old contents of RAX weren't precious, you would `mov $imm64, %rax` and use `(%rax)`.  Or  `movabs mem, %al` / `mov %al, %dil`, which even works if only the low 8 or 16 bits of RAX can be clobbered.  If it was a word load, then yes you could save a byte with 66 90+reg `xchg %ax, reg` instead of 3-byte `mov %ax,reg`, at the cost of more uops.)