# why we can't move a 64-bit immediate value to memory?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, cpu-architecture, instruction-set, immediate-operand

First I am a little bit confused with the differences between `movq` and `movabsq`, my text book says:

***The regular `movq` instruction can only have immediate source operands that can be represented as 32-bit two’s-complement numbers. This value is then sign extended to produce the 64-bit value for the destination. The `movabsq` instruction can have an arbitrary 64-bit immediate value as its source operand and can only have a register as a destination.***

I have two questions to this.

## Question 1

The `movq` instruction can only have immediate source operands that can be represented as 32-bit two’s-complement numbers.

so it means that we can't do

```
movq    $0x123456789abcdef, %rbp
```

and we have to do:

```
movabsq $0x123456789abcdef, %rbp
```

but why `movq` is designed to not work for 64 bits immediate value, which is really against the purpose of `q` (quard word), and we need to have another `movabsq` just for this purpose, isn't that hassle?

## Question 2

Since the destination of `movabsq` has to be a register, not memory, so we can't move a 64-bit immediate value to memory as:

```
movabsq $0x123456789abcdef, (%rax)
```

but there is a workaround:

```
movabsq $0x123456789abcdef, %rbx
movq    %rbx, (%rax)   // the source operand is a register, not immediate constant, and the destination of movq can be memory
```

so why the rule is designed to make things harder?

Comment: Note that `movq $0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF, (%rax)` *is* encodeable because the top 32 bits match bit #32.  All-F = all-ones which is the same as `-1` in 2's complement.  Something like `0x12345678abcd` that has more than 32 significant bits would work as an example.  (And be easier to grok than just leaving off one of the Fs.)

Comment: Also note that GAS assembles `movq    $0x123456789abcdef, %rbp` to the same machine code as `movabsq`.  It notices that the number won't fit in a 32-bit immediate and automatically chooses 64-bit, because that's possible for a register destination.  (It doesn't do that automatically for assemble-time constants that haven't been defined yet, or for addresses because addresses sometimes can be 32-bit.  So writing `movabs` explicitly is still sometimes necessary.)  All of that is unrelated to the actual question of why you can't have a memory destination, though.

Comment: The short answer to why we can't is because it isn't provided for in the instruction set.  A long answer would seek to justify why, but that really goes to design choices made long ago.

Answer (score 15):

Yes, `mov` to a register then to memory for immediates that won't fit in a sign-extended 32-bit, unlike `-1` aka `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`.  The *why* part is an interesting question, though:

---

Remember that assembly only lets you do what's possible *in machine code*.  Thus it's really a question about ISA design.  Such decisions often involve what's easy for the hardware to decode, as well as encoding efficiency considerations.  (Using up opcodes on rarely-used instructions would be bad.)

**It's not designed to make things harder, it's designed to not need any new opcodes for `mov`,** when AMD was extending x86 to 64-bit and aiming not to need a whole separate decoder unit for different modes.  And also to limit 64-bit immediates to one special instruction format.  `mov` is the only instruction that can *ever* use a 64-bit immediate *at all* (or a 64-bit absolute address, for load/store of AL/AX/EAX/RAX).

Check out [Intel's manual for the forms of `mov`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mov) (note that it uses Intel syntax, destination first, and so will my answer.)  I also summarized the forms (and their instruction lengths) in [Difference between movq and movabsq in x86-64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40315803/difference-between-movq-and-movabsq-in-x86-64), as did @MargaretBloom in answer to [What's the difference between the x86-64 AT&T instructions movq and movabsq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52434073/whats-the-difference-between-the-x86-64-att-instructions-movq-and-movabsq).

Allowing an imm64 along with a ModR/M addressing mode would also make it possible to run into the 15-byte upper limit on instruction length pretty easily, e.g. REX + opcode + imm64 is 10 bytes, and ModRM+SIB+disp32 is 6.  So `mov [rdi + rax*8 + 1234], imm64` would not be encodable even if there was an opcode for `mov r/m64, imm64`.

And that's assuming they repurposed one of the 1-byte opcodes that were freed up by making some instructions invalid in 64-bit mode (e.g. `aaa`), which might be inconvenient for the decoders (and instruction-length pre-decoders) because in other modes those opcodes don't take a ModRM byte or an immediate.

---

**`movq` is for the forms of `mov` with a normal ModRM byte to allow an arbitrary addressing mode as the destination.**  (Or as the source for `movq r64, r/m64`).  AMD chose to keep the immediate for these as 32-bit, same as with 32-bit operand size<sup>1</sup>.

These forms of `mov` are the same instruction format as other instructions like `add`.  **For ease of decoding, this means a REX prefix doesn't change the instruction length for these opcodes.**  Instruction-length decoding is already hard enough when the addressing mode is variable-length.

So `movq` is 64-bit operand-size but otherwise the same instruction format `mov r/m64, imm32` (becoming the sign-extended-immediate form, same as every other instruction which only has one immediate form), and `mov r/m64, r64` or `mov r64, r/m64`.

**`movabs` is the 64-bit form of the existing no-ModRM short form `mov reg, imm32`**.  This one is already a special case (because of the no-ModRM encoding, with register number from the low 3 bits of the opcode byte).  Small positive constants can just use 32-bit operand size for implicit zero-extension to 64-bit with no loss of efficiency (like 5-byte `mov eax, 123` / AT&T `mov $123, %eax` in 32 or 64-bit mode).  And having a 64-bit absolute `mov` is useful so it makes sense AMD did that.

Since there's no ModRM byte, it can only encode a register destination.  It would take a whole different opcode to add a form that could take a memory operand.

---

From one POV, be grateful you get a `mov` with 64-bit immediates *at all*; RISC ISAs like AArch64 (with fixed-width 32-bit instructions) need more like 4 instructions just to get a 64-bit value into a register. (Unless it's a repeating bit-pattern; AArch64 is actually pretty cool. Unlike earlier RISCs like MIPS64 or PowerPC64)

**If AMD64 was going to introduce a new opcode for `mov`, `mov r/m, sign_extended_imm8` would be vastly more useful to save code size.**  It's not at all rare for compilers to emit multiple `mov qword ptr [rsp+8], 0` instructions to zero a local array or struct, each one containing a 4-byte `0` immediate.  Putting a non-zero small number in a register is fairly common, and would make `mov eax, 123` a 3-byte instruction (down from 5), and `mov rax, -123` a 4-byte instruction (down from 7).  It would also make zeroing a register without clobbering FLAGS 3 bytes.

Allowing `mov` imm64 to memory would be useful rarely enough that AMD decided it wasn't worth making the decoders more complex. I agree with them in this case, but AMD was very conservative with adding new opcodes. So many missed opportunities to clean up x86 warts, like widening `setcc` would have been nice. (Intel *finally* got around to this [with APX](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/technical/advanced-performance-extensions-apx.html) providing REX2 and EVEX prefixes for a zero-upper form of `setcc`.) But I think AMD wasn't sure AMD64 would catch on and didn't want to be stuck needing a lot of extra transistors and/or power to support a feature if people didn't use it.

**Footnote 1**:
32-bit immediates in general is pretty obviously a good decision for code size.  It's very rare to want to `add` an immediate to something that's outside the +-2GiB range.  It could be useful for bitwise stuff like `AND`, but for setting/clearing/flipping a single bit the `bts` / `btr` / `btc` instructions are good (taking a bit-position as an 8-bit immediate, instead of needing a mask).  You don't want `sub rsp, 1024` to be an 11-byte instruction; 7 is already bad enough.

---

#### Giant instructions? Not very efficient

At the time AMD64 was designed (early 2000s), CPUs with uop caches weren't a thing.  (Intel P4 with a trace cache did exist, but it is regarded as a mistake in hindsight.)  Instruction fetch/decode happens in chunks of up-to-16 bytes, so having one instruction that's nearly 16 bytes isn't much better for the front end than `movabs $imm64, %reg`.

Of course, if the back-end isn't keeping up with the front-end, that bubble of only 1 instruction decoded this cycle can be hidden by buffering between stages.

**Keeping track of that much data for one instruction would also be a problem**.  The CPU has to put that data somewhere, and if there's a 64-bit immediate *and* a 32-bit displacement in the addressing mode, that's a lot of bits.  **Normally an instruction needs at most 64 bits of space for an imm32 + a disp32.**

---

BTW, there are special no-ModRM opcodes for most operations with RAX and an immediate.  (x86-64 evolved out of 8086, where AX/AL was more special, see [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/132981/tips-for-golfing-in-x86-x64-machine-code/160739#160739) for more history and explanation). It would have been a plausible design for those `add/sub/cmp/and/or/xor/... rax, sign_extended_imm32` forms with no ModRM to instead use a full imm64. The most common case for RAX, immediate uses an 8-bit sign-extended immediate (-128..127), not this form anyway, and it only saves 1 byte for instructions that need a 4-byte immediate.  If you do need an 8-byte constant, though, putting it in a register or memory for reuse would be better than doing a 10-byte and-imm64 in a loop, though.

Answer (score 5):

**For the first question:**

From the [official documentation of gnu assembler](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/i386_002dVariations.html):

> In 64-bit code, `movabs` can be used to encode the `mov` instruction with the 64-bit displacement or immediate operand.

`mov reg64, imm` (in intel syntax, destination first) is the only instruction that accepts a 64-bit immediate value as a parameter. That's why you can't write a 64-bit immediate value directly to memory, only to a register.  That form of `mov` uses an opcode that includes a register number, rather than specifying a reg/mem destination via a ModRM byte.

---

**For the second question:**

For other destinations, for example a memory location, a 32-bit immediate can be sign-extended to a 64-bit immediate (which means the top 33 bits are the same there). In this case, you use the `movq` instruction.

This is also possible if the target is a register, saving 3 bytes:

```
48 B8 FF FF FF 7F 00 00 00 00   movabs $0x7FFFFFFF, %rax
48 C7 C0 FF FF FF 7F            movq   $0x7FFFFFFF, %rax
```

At the 64-bit immediate `0xFFFFFFFF`, the top 33 bits are not the same (`00...`), so `movl` cannot be used here. That's why I chose `0x7FFFFFFF` in this example. But there is another option:

When writing to a 32-bit register (the lower part of a 64-bit register), the upper 32-bit of the register are zeroed. For a 64-bit immediate whose upper 32-bits are zero, `movl` can therefore also be used, which saves another a byte:

```
# with mov $imm32, reg/mem32.  Assemblers won't use this for a register destination
C7 C0 FF FF FF FF               movl   $0xFFFFFFFF, %eax
```

A further byte is saved by the assembler using the special case mov-to-register encoding.  (`movabs`-immediate is the REX.W form of this opcode.)

```
# the mov $imm32, reg  short-form encoding with no ModRM
B8 FF FF FF FF                  movl   $0xFFFFFFFF, %eax
```

GAS and other assemblers will automatically use the shortest encoding for the instruction you actually wrote, e.g. they'll encode `mov $-1, %eax` in 5 bytes.

---

But GAS does *not* automatically optimize `%rax` to `%eax`.  For example, `mov $0x00000000FFFFFFFF, %rax` will use 10-byte `movabsq`, not `movl`.

It can also choose between `movabs` and `movq` if you use `mov`, depending on the size of the immediate.  e.g. `mov $1, %rax`.  But won't optimize that to a 5-byte mov-immediate with 32-bit operand-size.

But if you use `as -Os` (or or `gcc -Wa,-Os`), GAS *will* use the 5-byte `movl $-1, %eax` encoding for `mov $0xFFFFFFFF, %rax`.  It has the same architectural effect (one instruction that makes RAX=0x00000000FFFFFFFF), but it's spelled differently in the asm source; using a different operand-size and thus a different register name.

NASM does this optimization (to a different operand-size) by default.

Comment: If fixed some bugs in your answer, have a look at the edit log message.  Notably, GAS does *not* optimize `movq` to `movl`, only between `movq` and `movabsq` depending on the immediate.  You might want to say something else.  Your answer is now not wrong, but I'm not sure it's useful.

Comment: Thanks, I messed up something there.

Comment: Yep, and even mov RAX,0x8765432187654321 is going to get broken into 2 uop entries by the decoders. The microarchitectures are optimized for the common case, 32b and less.

Comment: @Olsonist: Only in the uop cache.  It's a single uop in the decoders and the issue stage (and ROB/RS).  But yes, Agner Fog reports that imm64 (if the value isn't a zero-extended 32-bit value) takes 2 entries in a uop cache line, and maybe even takes an extra cycle to read from the uop cache.