# Assembly, Moving 64-bit Immediate to memory?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, opcode, mov, instruction-encoding

I was reading:

[why we can't move a 64-bit immediate value to memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62771323/why-we-cant-move-a-64-bit-immediate-value-to-memory)

In one of the answers it's mentioned:

> mov reg64, imm (in intel syntax, destination first) is the only
> instruction that accepts a 64-bit immediate value as a parameter.
> That's why you can't write a 64-bit immediate value directly to
> memory.

Isn't this a clear contradiction? On the one hand he is saying this instruction accepts 64-bit immediate value. One the other hand, he is saying that's why you can't use 64-bit immediate value!

I am totally lost, why the relation is "That's why" That's a contradiction for clear and he proved why we CAN move a 64-bit immediate to memmory?

Comment: The instruction in question writes to a **register**, not to memory.  Note "reg64", not "r/m64".  Since this instruction does not write to memory, and it is the only instruction to accept a 64-bit immediate, we do in fact conclude that there is no instruction that writes a 64-bit immediate to memory.

Comment: I edited that paragraph in [the answer you quoted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62771800/224132) to make it easier for future readers to see the point it's making.  The question itself already mentions the `mov` vs. `movabs` names AT&T syntax uses for the two forms that do/don't accept a memory destination, and my answer explains why that makes sense and has some details and links.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks