# Error: operand type mismatch for `add' immediate value GNU Assembler intel syntax

Tags: assembly, x86-64, gnu-assembler, instruction-set

I tried this simple assembly:

```
add r9, 0x4014000000000000
```

It gave me error:

```
Error: operand type mismatch for `add'
```

I also try:

```
addq r9, 0x4014000000000000 #(second operand is 64-bit)
```

which q stand for quad 64-bit, CMIIW.

I'm sure `r9` is 64-bit wide.

I also try:

```
add r9, 0xffffffffffffffff #(second operand is 64-bit too)
```

But this time where second operand is `0xffffffffffffffff` which it's 64-bit operand is working fine, so what was happened?

Comment: immediates are still 32-bit. sign extended. Not all of them. But they are for `add`.

Comment: ```0xffffffffffffffff``` is 64-bit, but it works no error.

Comment: Yeah, it's a 64-bit value that can be sign-extended from a 32-bit immediate.  The signed value it represents is `-1`.  Near duplicate of [why we can't move a 64-bit immediate value to memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62771323)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no encoding that supports a 64-bit immediate on the `add` instruction, just like it is the case for the majority of instructions.

To `add r9, 0x4014000000000000`, move the immediate to a scratch register and add that to R9.

```
mov rax, 0x4014000000000000
add r9, rax
```

Your `add r9, 0xffffffffffffffff` instruction does work because in this case 'the very big' immediate value is in fact just **-1**, and that's a value that nicely fits the encoding that sign-extends a 32-bit immediate into a 64-bit value. The assembler will even do better and use a single byte immediate to encode this instruction.
Your `add r9, 0xffffffffffffffff` is actually `add r9, -1`.

For 64-bit values in [0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFF80, 0x000000000000007F], (-128, +127) the assembler encodes a sign-extendable 8-bit immediate.
For 64-bit values in [0xFFFFFFFF80000000, 0x000000007FFFFFFF], (-2147483648, +2147483647) the assembler encodes a sign-extendable 32-bit immediate.
Other 64-bit values cannot be encoded.